# What information is stored in a python map object?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I'm not able to wrap my mind on the map() function.
I have taken code from an [example](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/demos/classifier.py).
I'd like to know what exactly happen on this line of code.

```
labels = map(itemgetter(1),map(os.path.split,map(os.path.dirname,labels)))
```

The values of labels before this statement is

```
<class 'list'>: ['classify-test/aligned/clapton/clapton-1.png', 'classify-test/aligned/clapton/clapton-2.png', 'classify-test/aligned/lennon/lennon-1.png', 'classify-test/aligned/lennon/lennon-2.png']
```

I know that If I did  `map(os.path.split,map(os.path.dirname, labels[0]))` I'd get the value `clapton`.

But can I use some other logic to conver this map. And what is the return type of the     `labels=map(itemgetter(1),map(os.path.split,map(os.path.dirname,labels)))` line.

Is it a list of strings or someting else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following pure-Python implementation of `map`:

```
def my_map (func, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        yield func(item)
```

This is essentially was the built-in `map` does, just in native code, so it’s a lot faster.

So `map` will just apply the function passed as the first argument to every single element of the iterable passed as the second argument. In your case, to understand what happens, you should read the line from the inside to the outside:

```
map(itemgetter(1), map(os.path.split, map(os.path.dirname, labels)))
                                                           ^^^^^^
                                               Start here: This is your iterable

                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                          Run os.path.dirname(x) on every element x

                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       Run os.path.split(y) on every element y of the previous result

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Run itemgetter(1)(z) on every element z of the previous result
```

Since you are running `map` three times, you are applying three functions on the original element. You could combine those functions to make it a bit more clear:

```
def getDirectoryName(label):
    return os.path.split(os.path.dirname(label))[1]

result = map(getDirectoryName, labels)
```

Having those function calls properly chained makes this already a lot clearer, which allows us to easily guess what the combined function does: In this case, it gets the directory of the passed label (which is a path), and then splits that up, to get just the name of the directory. One could also use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) here instead of splitting the path manually.

Because this is so much clearer, this is the reason why you rarely see `map` being used in Python code. The often preferred way would be to use a list comprehension:

```
result = [os.path.split(os.path.dirname(label))[1] for label in labels]
```

Here you have the benefit of both: Everything in a concise way, yet easy to understand since it’s imperative code instead of functional.